# Using images in 2 different django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a retail site selling multiple brands. Each brand has its logo on its own page. The logo images are in their own model.

How do I use the same logo for a different model on the index page? I'd like to use the same logos while highlighting some store coupons in the sidebar.

Currently, I have a Foreign Key to the store in the IMG model.

current code:

`models.py`

```
class Logo(models.Model):
     store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     related_name="storelogo")
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

`views.py`

```
def show_store(request, slug):
    store = Store.objects.get(slug=slug)
    uploads = store.storelogo.all()

    return render(request, 'store.html', {
            'store': store,
            'products': products,
            'coupons': coupons,
            'uploads': uploads,
        })
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="store-logo">
    {% for logo in store.storelogo.all %}
        <img src="{{ logo.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The logo shows fine on the store page but I can't get it to show in a For loop on the index page. Is it possible?

I could add another image model and add the exact same logo images for the coupons but it seems to be totally against DRY principles. Are there template tags I can use on an index page or is it best to create another model?

Let me know if I left anything out. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the loop should iterate over store.logo.all instead of store.storelogo.all in the html, since your logo model is named as logo()

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, you could send the store details as a context to the index html page, or you can use a template tag too, and then iterate over the data.

Comment: You should send the logo image in context processor so that it can be accessible in different html without sending it repeatedly .You will have to add context processor in settings.py and will have to create a context_processor.py where you have to return the logo corresponding to store. You can visit **https://rock-it.pl/how-to-make-your-django-context-processors-lazy/** for more vision.